# why the curve for smoothing term different?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

[image]

According to what i had read,that  An edf of 2 is equivalent to a quadratic curve, but my plot does not look like quadratic curve. i want to know the reason. This the link for that i refer to https://noamross.github.io/gams-in-r-course/chapter2

[image]

I wanted to add another question, what make plot curve in fb.ratio different from SOM even when both had edf=2?

It is because of the distribution for observation data point in fb.ratio more disperse while SOM observation more collected in group?

Comment: Please don't edit questions to *add* new questions. It's better to have a single question per thread, and substantial edits to the question will invalidate existing answers. Instead. please ask a new self-contained question. (Do feel free to link here from the new question, and from this one to the new one, to provide context.)

Answer (score 1):

Your plot looks quite quadratic to me.

It's all a question of scaling the vertical axis. Here are two plots of $y=x^2$. In the left one, the $y$ axis is scaled so the curve fills the vertical space, in the right one the $y$ axis is scaled (and the $x$ axis is truncated) to give something similar to your data - *but both plots show the same parabola*:

[image: parabola]

R code:

```
xx <- seq(-1,1,.0001)
yy <- xx^2
opar <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(xx,yy,type="l",xlab="",ylab="",las=1)
plot(xx,yy,type="l",xlab="",ylab="",las=1,xlim=c(-.5,1), ylim=c(-5,7))
```